# Replace Observable which already has subscribers with other Observable

Tags: rxjs

I have an `Observable` which gets later gets "replace" with another `Observable`.

How can I swap the `Observable` without loosing my subscribers?

```
const source = NEVER

const source2 = interval(1000);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// source.switch(source2)
```

`source.switch(source2)` is obviously not a valid operation. But it demonstrates, what I'dlike to achieve.
Same example on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-76a7ew

What would I need to do after the subscribtion, so this code will start printing the numbers from `interval`?

Comment: You usually use `switchMap` to map to another observable but this switch will never happen if your first observable is `NEVER`. Why would you want to switch from `NEVER` to a different observable?

Answer (score 0):

so you want switch to source2

```
source.pipe(
 switchMap(() => source2)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // x here is source2
```

you could use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` as well but I would recommend to use `switchMap` in this case as it's going to cancel the previous emit